# Change BackgroundImage from CSS using JS

Tags: javascript

I have a problem and don't know the solution.
Here is my HTML

```
<div id="thumb">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#thumb {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 557px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(252, 191, 73, 0.3),
      rgba(252, 191, 73, 0.3)
    ),
    url("../img/thumb.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
```

JS:

```
var sliderGet = document.getElementById("thumb").style.backgroundImage;
  sliderGet = 'url("../img/thumb2.jpg")';
```

There is no way to change to thumb2.jpg using js...

Comment: try 
`document.getElementById("thumb").style.backgroundImage = 'url("../img/thumb2.jpg")'`

Comment: Imagine you did `var x = 3; x = 5;`.  Would you expect `3` to change?

Comment: Not knowing how to do something <> not being possible to do.

Comment: you might want to try this $('#thumb').css('background-image', 'url("../img/thumb2.jpg")'); .. you can put this on `onCLick`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`document.getElementById("thumb").style.backgroundImage = 'url("../img/thumb2.jpg")'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it directly.

```
document.getElementById("thumb").style.backgroundImage = 'url("../img/thumb2.jpg")'
```